# How to delete series in chart if series name = "#N/A"

Tags: vba, excel, charts, legend

I have a dynamic chart which may sometimes include empty data series in excel vba. When there is an empty data series, only the legend entry shows as "#N/A". I am trying to build a code which will delete the data series entirely if the series name is equal to "#N/A." Below is a copy of the code I have build however I get an invalid parameter error at the "for each..." line.

```
Dim n As Variant
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
For Each n In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n)
    If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Name.Text = "#N/A" Then
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Delete
    End If
Next n
```

Comment: Have you got an example of what your data and chart looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Dim n As Series
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select 
For Each n In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    If n.Name = "#N/A" Then
        n.Delete
    End If
Next n
```